# Can I dockerize a WCF application in a linux container?

Tags: c#, docker, wcf, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to dockerize a WCF application in a Linux container. It this possible? I tried to add Docker support from Visual Studio but I don't have an option for a Linux container.

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question.

Comment: WCF is not supported by .Net Core, so I assume that you are using .Net Framework.   .Net Framework only works on Windows -- so not Linux.   If you want to change the application to .Net Core you need to replace the WCF code with something else, such as Core WCF.   See https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/blog/2019/06/07/welcoming-core-wcf-to-the-net-foundation